# Allowing minecraft through a proxy server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

- System: Debian 10
- Minecraft version: 1.12.2 (Optifine)

My local internet connects via proxy and I'm trying to play on minecraft servers. I've already excluded port **25565** from the proxy server, but I still get an error when trying to connect to a server (mostly mc.hypixel.net). The error is:

"**Failed to login : The authentication servers are currently down for maintenance**"

This doesn't always pop up, **1/4** of the time I successfully connect to the server. I'm sure that it's not an issue with the authentication servers down, because when I refresh the number of players on the server, the number is sometimes going up. I want to know if there are any other ports / adreses that have to be unlocked in order for minecraft multiplayer to work.

Comment: Possibly related...? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203582/unable-to-connect-to-authentication-servers-on-debian-vps - see the up voted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minecraft authentication on online mode servers (almost all of them, including hypixel) involves both the client and server going to different endpoints on https://sessionserver.mojang.com/ to verify the legitimacy of the user.

Specifically, the client goes to https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/join.

Depending on what your proxy does, this may be the reason why you're having issues, and you may want to whitelist this host too. [You can read more about these endpoints here](https://wiki.vg/Protocol_Encryption).